# How can I import data from Excel to SAGA?

Tags: excel, saga

I have just started using SAGA and I want to plot some geographic coordinates (latitudes and longitudes) and I want to import them from Excel. Please tell me what to do from Excel to when the points are plotted.

Comment: What information is in your excel files?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, try exporting your data as tab-seperated textfile (in save as).
You can open this file in saga by using open table.

You will want to run the module `modules\shapes\convert table to point` to convert your table to points.